# Best Approach for developing app that mainly calls stored procedures through Spring and Struts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts, mybatis

First post at stackoverflow after I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I am developing an application that will mainly just take input parameters from a user and pass them to Oracle stored procedures. None of the stored procedures return anything since their purpose is only to maintain a schedule for running a bunch of ODIs. The only time the app will actually fetch and return data from the database would be to display the current schedule. I am using Java 1.7 in Eclipse. Definitely using Struts 2 and Spring but can't decide if I should use Spring JDBC, Hibernate, or myBatis for the data layer. 
Which combination would work the best when 90% of the database operation is only running stored procedures that don't return anything? I would have to learn either one of them from scratch, so the one with less steep learning curve would be nicer.

Thanks.

p.s. From what I have learned so far, myBatis would probably be the best approach but could not find as many good examples for integration and running stored procedures as I could for Hibernate.

Comment: Why would you need any O/R module if you don't have any work for it to do?

Comment: A little tip: [Don't use stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661772/how-to-make-a-mysql-app-using-only-stored-procedures/6661967#6661967).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple.  Use straight JDBC.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html

Comment: I agree with this answer. Requirement is pretty simple, so better to keep solution also simple. Go for JDBC or Spring JDBC.